# Изменение места в рейтинге

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Есть таблица рейтинга, столбцы Участник, Место и Баллы
Вот строки

```
user1 1 100
user2 2 67
user3 3 50
user4 4 1
```

Как сделать изменение мест при увеличении очков? Например, user4 набрал 68 очков, ему присваивается 2 место и 68 прибавляется к его нынешним очкам, user3 - 3 место, user4 - 4 место

Comment: скачать участников и рейтинги из БД в память, выполнить ранжирование или что вам надо сделать, отправить места в базу

Comment: Просто заново пересчитать все места.

Comment: @tym32167 А какой смысл туда-сюда гонять всю таблицу, когда MySQL легко сделает это у себя?

Comment: @Akina можно в памяти приложения, можно в памяти MySQL. У каждого подхода есть и плюсы и минусы.

Comment: @tym32167 Можно узнать минусы при выполнении операции на стороне MySQL? я их как-то не наблюдаю...

Comment: @Akina аргументы агалогичные аргументам в войне между бизнес логикой в хранимках и в коде. Вы ещё не участвовали в такой дискуссии?

Comment: @tym32167 кхм. Ради того чтобы реализовывать логику не на стороне БД мы копируем всю таблицу?) А потом ещё и обратно загружаем. Да я бы вообще не хранил место текущее. Вычисляемое поле и пойдёт.

Comment: @tym32167 В данном случае они неприменимы - тут простая сортировка по убыванию, и единственная вариабельная точка - это что делать при одинаковом количестве баллов. Причём любой из трёх вариантов легко реализуется в запросе. *Вычисляемое поле и пойдёт.* Тоже хорошо.

Comment: @pavel я не знаю количество данных в таблице. Для миллиона участников конечно с вами соглашусь, для 10 участников разницы нет абсолютно никакой что делать.

Comment: @Akina может и так, я просто прочитал вопрос, не понял, что именно и как автор хочет прибавлять к рейтингам, подумал, что проще это будет в коде прописать. Но ваш вариант тоже имеет право на жизнь. По мне, как я уже написал, я бы смотрел на количество данных и на сложность того, как это запрограммировать.

Comment: @Akina давайте поглядим на эту задачу с другой стороны. Это же расчет рейтинга, так? То есть какое то время идет соревнование и потом, в определенный момент скажем, ночью, раз в неделю/месяц запускается этот расчет. Если это предположение верно, чисто по моему опыту, не имеет никакой разницы, будет этот расчет идти 1 секунду или 10 минут. С такими условиями все таки нет разницы, с точки зрения функциональности, как оно будет выполнено.

Comment: @tym32167 Как по моему опыту - если это не оффлайн-соревнование, то даже минутная задержка в публикации свежих результатов и обновлении рейтинга вызывает просто шквал воплей.

Comment: @Akina если имеет место требование по скорости и участников достаточно много то да, сделать это в SQL будет лучше, тут даже обсуждать нечего :)